# View lists in appweb created by addin

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-addin

How can I view list(s) which are in app web, created by SharePoint Add-in?

For example in host web I can see lists in Site Contents on this URL

```
https://tenant_name.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14
```

So how can I see lists of app web, suppose this is my app web URL?

```
https://tenant_name-e2b4688698c43a.sharepoint.com/sites/site2.....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the list name, you can view the specific list by appending /lists/ to the app web url

Ex : https://tenant_name-e2b4688698c43a.sharepoint.com/sites/site2/lists/ListName

If you want to know about all lists you can use REST API which will show the xml feed of list details.
Ex : 
https://tenant_name-e2b4688698c43a.sharepoint.com/sites/site2/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false and BaseType ne 1

This will return the xml feed of all lists(including system lists)

[image]

Comment: I tried it's not working !

Comment: when you say its not working. What response are you getting ? If possible share the REST URL you are hitting in the browser as well.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint apps don't have own setting page or any navigation to traverse to list, list settings.

You need to create link for traverse to site content as below:

http://app-web-url/_layouts/15/mcontent.aspx

For more detail please check [this](http://sharepointcore.blogspot.in/2015/08/how-to-view-sharepoint-app-web-site-contents.html) link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way

https://tenant_name.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/appname1/Lists/list1/Allitems.aspx

https://********.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/*****/Lists/*****/Allitems.aspx

**tenant_name** is the app created URL

**site1** is the name of site collection or site

**appname1** is the name of app or Add-in

**list1** is the list name

Taken from

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharatgupta/2013/03/10/sharepoint-2013-app-model-how-to-view-list-list-settings-inside-app/